# linux - after rsync, du shows size difference when diff does not

Tags: linux, diff, rsync, du

I copied a large folder from NTFS to ext4 using 'rsync' and validating it with 'diff'. Just for the shake of curiosity, I also used 'du' command to check if folders had the same size. While 'diff' didn't show any difference, 'du' showed that folders had different sizes. I did not encounter any errors while executing the following commands.

```
rsync --archive --recursive "$src" "$dest" 2>rsync_error.txt

sync

diff --brief --recursive --new-file "$src" "$dest" 1>diff-log.txt 2>diff-error.txt
```

Then I used 'du' for each folder:

```
du -sb "$src"
du -sb "$dest"
Output:
137197597476
137203512004
```

1.Why would this happen since there is not any difference?

2.Should I be worried about my data or my system?

EDIT:
I also tried `du -s --apparent-size` and there is still difference.

Comment: What's your *filesystem*? (on both side, are them same?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sparses files

Under linux, you could create so-called [*`sparse files`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). They are files where full `NULL` block don't really exists!

Try this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero count=2048 of=normalfile
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0103269 s, 102 MB/s
```

and

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero count=0 seek=2048 of=sparsefile
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000182708 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

then

```
$ ls -l sparsefile normalfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  1048576 Feb  3 17:53 normalfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  1048576 Feb  3 17:53 sparsefile

$ du -b sparsefile normalfile
1048576     sparsefile
1048576     normalfile
```

but

```
$ du -k sparsefile normalfile
0   sparsefile
1024        normalfile

$ du -h sparsefile normalfile
0   sparsefile
1.0M        normalfile
```

So long block in `sparsefile` are not used, they will not be *allocated*!

```
$ du -k --apparent-size sparsefile normalfile
1024        sparsefile
1024        normalfile
```

Then

```
$ diff sparsefile normalfile
echo $?
0
```

There is virtually no difference between both files!

#### Further

```
$ /sbin/mkfs.ext4 sparsefile 
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Filesystem too small for a journal
...
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ ls -l sparsefile normalfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  1048576 Feb  3 17:53 normalfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  1048576 Feb  3 17:59 sparsefile

$ du -k sparsefile 
32  sparsefile

$ diff sparsefile normalfile
Binary files sparsefile and normalfile differ
```

Comment: Of course, 1Mb is something small for installing a filesystem, but this is only for a demo.

Comment: I think the reason that happens is a combination of how OS handles files (like EOF character) and sparse files. In my NTFS partition some files are made under windows. If you make a file under Linux and again under Windows there will be a slight difference in bytes while the content is the same.

Comment: @invinciblecache No, a file is a file. The way of creating them is same. *`EOF`* don't matter in this. If files differs, `diff` will show them! For NTFS sparse files, you could read http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-sparse.htm

Comment: Following your example, I did 'rsync sparsefile sparsefile2' and 'du -k' shows 'sparsefile2' like 'normalfile'. However, If i do 'cp sparsefile sparsefile3', 'du -k'  shows 'sparsefile3' like 'sparsefile'. It seems that it's all down to how rsync works and not dependent on filesystem or operating system. I think it would be good to add this observation to your answer.

Comment: Both commands `rsync` and `cp` have option `--sparse`!  See manpages!

Answer (score 1):

Greettings Invinciblecache,

Googling around I've found this:

> As du reports allocation space and not absolute file space, the amount of space on a file system shown by du may vary from that shown by df if files have been deleted but their blocks not yet freed. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix))

Not the best source but is a great description of what `du` is used for.

So, I'd rely on `diff` to check the content of the files, but I would recommend to ignore size difference on filesystem unless it is too high, which is not this the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`du` is reporting space including filesystem space, not only file content size.

Also check for hidden files which might not be included in your `du`.

Comment: I also tried 'du -s --apparent-size' and it shows difference. I found that's because of sparse files.